# How to select a combination which gives me maximum accuracy of that row/combination?

Tags: matlab

**I am using R2015a.** I have this function which gives me the accuracy of the predicted classes using the knnclassify function.

```
function [acc]=knnAccuracy(sample,training,group,actual,z)
result = knnclassify(sample, training, group, z);
t = result';
a = actual';

count=1;
correct=0;
while count<=size(t)
    for i=t
        k = a(count);

        if isequal(i,k);
            correct=correct+1;
        end
        count=count+1;
    end
end
b=correct(end);
accuracy=((b./size(t))*100);
acc=accuracy(end);
end
```

Here, Sample Training are matrices, having an equal number of rows. The group is the associated class related to each column [see knnclassify() for detalis](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html/%22knnclassify()%22). This functions compares the results of the knnclassify with the actual cell array given in the function and calculates the accuracy.

Now, I have this code which gives me all the possible combinations of the rows of the matrix inMat as follows.

```
inMat = magic(5); % this represent your input
for n = 1:length(inMat)
    rowsCell = num2cell(inMat,2);
    r = nchoosek(1:size(inMat,1),n);
    out = cell2mat(reshape(rowsCell(r.',:).',n,1,[]))
end
```

At first iteration, it gives me combinations of only 1 row than it gives me combinations of 2 rows and so on. Now on the first iteration, I will apply knnaccuracy on all combinations and then **I want to select that row/combination which gives me the maximum accuracy and then I need all the possible 2-row combinations of that matrix with that certain row which we just found out which gives us a maximum accuracy.** Moving on I need all three-row combinations with that specific 2-row combination which we found previously that gives the maximum sum. With each iteration, I will also check if the accuracy is increasing or not if it is decreased or remained the same I will have to stop here and At the end of the day I will consider that combination at hand to be the smallest possible combination that gives maximin accuracy.

Comment: Your wording is hard to follow.  I think I might understand what you are asking.   But this question could be better if you showed your desired output   Also, if I understand what you are asking for correctly using `magic(5)` as your sample input was probably a bad choice.   `magic` squares by definition have the equal row and column sums.  So to find a row with the maximum sum makes no sense ... all the row sums are identical.

Comment: magic is just for example I need to do a bit complicated thing actually.  I need to apply this function which gives us accuracy on each combination.

Comment: I am gonna edit the post I hope you will understand.

Comment: I have edited the post have a look.

Answer (score 1):

When I interpreted your question the right way, your looking for something like this. The first input argument is your matrix and the second input is the number of rows you'd like to combine.

```
rowComb = getMaxSumCombination(inMat, 2);

function rowComb = getMaxSumCombination(inMat, nrRows)
    rowSums = sortrows([(1:size(inMat,1)).', sum(inMat, 2)], 2, 'descend');
    rowComb = inMat(rowSums(1:nrRows, 1), :);
end
```

Comment: This was my interpretation as well.  I was going to suggest something very similar.

Comment: what is your suggestion by the way @Aero

Comment: @AliHassan Same process.  Sum matrix by rows, sort results descending.  Take N rows off the top of the sort...